# return more than 1 value in @ table variable

Tags: sql-server-2005

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_DivisonCode] (@PeopleID int)
RETURNS @temptable TABLE (Code varchar(100), ID varchar(100))
AS
begin

DECLARE @stDeptCode VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @peopleID VARCHAR(100)

SELECT 
      @stDeptCode = (COALESCE(@stDeptCode + ',', '') + CAST(PPL.DeptCode AS VARCHAR(5))),
      @peopleID = peopleID
FROM dbo.PPL
WHERE PeopleID = peopleID 

INSERT INTO @temptable(Code, ID) 
  VALUES(@stDeptCode, @peopleID)

return
end

SELECT [dbo].[fn_DivisonCode](23415)
```

When I call the function it should return 2 values but here it returns only the `@stDeptCod` values not the `@peopleID`. Is there anything that I am missing here?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You are selecting values into variables. A variable can only hold a single value at a time, so when you run your select statement, it may select one, or two, or 100 values from the table, but only the last one is stored in the variable after the statement completes. Instead, combine you select and insert statements, like this:

```
insert into @temptable(Code,ID)
  SELECT (COALESCE(@stDeptCode + ',', '')  +  CAST(PPL.DeptCode AS VARCHAR(5))), peopleID
    FROM dbo.PPL  
    WHERE @PeopleID = peopleID
```

Comment: by calling the function like this it works fine select * FROM [dbo].[fn_DivisonCode](23415)